# How can I delete a remote Git repository from the command line (Git Bash)?

Tags: git, github, repository

**I'm trying to remove a remote git repository through Git Bash.** I'm aware that I can just delete it through GitHub; however, I want to learn how to do so through the command line. I don't just want to remove the files in it, or replace it, I want to completely delete it. I spent the last two days sifting through forums, articles, blogs and tutorials, and nothing has worked.

**Some initial info:**

```
$ git remote -v
thisbranch https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git (fetch)
thisbranch https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git (push)

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git log
Author: *info*
Date: *info*
   adding a new file
Author: *info*
Date: *info*
   Initial commit

$ git remote -v show thisbranch
* remote thisbranch
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git
  Push URL: https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

**Some things I tried:**

```
$ git remote remove https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.https://github.com/thisuser/test-repo.git'

$ git remote remove master
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.master'

$ git remote remove thisbranch
*returns nothing*

$ git remote -v
*returns nothing*
```

I've realized I also never get returned the name 'origin'.

Comment: In Oct. 2021, there is now `gh repo delete`: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718110/6309).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out by BrokenBinary in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868636/how-to-remove-a-git-repository/27868996#comment44139745_27868636),

> This can't be done.

You cannot delete a remote repo (hosted on GitHub or elsewhere) with Git commands, be it in Git Bash or elsewhere, period. You can [delete remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely) (assuming you have write access to them), yes, but not an entire remote repository.

However, the [GitHub Developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository) allows you to delete, at the command line, a repo hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

As Jubobs mentioned above you can use github dev API, so:
`curl -u :username -X "DELETE" https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repo`
Where **:username** = your username(github handler) and **:repo** = a name of a repo you want to get rid of

Answer (score 1):

This now (Oct. 2021) can be done from command-line, using [`gh repo delete`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_delete), added in the [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.2.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.2.0)

This is from the [feature request 3625](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3625) (Add feature to delete a repository from command line), fixed in [PR 4451](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/4451), and [commit 5a3b9ce](https://github.com/cli/cli/commit/5a3b9ceab02fd0225a6ecbfb948e9a77a3628fde).

It does wrap the `curl -u :username -X "DELETE" https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repo` mentioned in [daGo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4814774/dago)'s 2017 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46552969/6309).

Answer (score 1):

First, switch to sudo mode:

```
gh auth refresh -h github.com -s delete_repo
```

After the signup, then you can:

```
gh repo delete
```

**Note**: This only deletes the remote repository. To delete it locally, go to the parent directory and use the command `rm -r dirname`; replace `dirname` with the name of your directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete the repository.

First we need to add repository:

```
git remote add origin <repository link>
```

If we want to delete repository:

```
git remote remove origin
```

then press enter button

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34687193)