# Remove a repository with a valid ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868996/10189759
but it is not about ssh key

So, ssh is a common way of authenticating GitHub to read or write a repository.

since ssh key **don't** provide a read-only option, I want to know other than **write** (removing all commit, etc), what else could be dangerous.

**Could I remove a repository using a valid ssh key?**

=====================================================
ps: hope github could provide read-only option to ssh key in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could I remove a repository using a valid ssh key?

Remote repository- No. You must need to use online portal in order to delete a repository with admin access.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-a-repository

More security options on using SSH - https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-ssh-certificate-authorities

**Update**:

I contacted Github support and got their response on this as well after posting this answer.

[image]

Github support has also mentioned the same link of documentation about deleting a remote repository.

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer, however, the two links you provide didn't prove that an online portal is the only way to delete a repository.

Comment: @LukAron however, that's a legitimate source of information regarding that. I am sure if it would be possible, they would include that in the documentation saying that yes you can do using online portal and ssh key, but, there's not.

Comment: @LukAron I updated my answer, Its clear now that you cannot delete a remote repo using ssh key.

Comment: That's the power of StackOverflow.  Thanks.      However, the reply from the GitHub support is not accurate. Clearly, API could do this as well,  for your information, https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#delete-a-repository , but knowing that ssh key couldn't do such a dangerous thing is enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

Your user would have permissions which are set on GitHub, if you have the permissions to perform the actions, then the user will  be able to do so. An administrator should be giving access which is necessary only.

More information is available at the following GitHub webpage,

https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/access-permissions-on-github

Comment: I am curious, so do you mean we can delete a remote repository using ssh command line?

Comment: so you are not answering the question at all.

Comment: I do know you can use `git push (remote name) --delete branch` to remove a branch on the remote repository at present.

Comment: I know this applies for GitLab at least, when GitLab is installed on the server, by default a git user is created, the permissions are set for this user. When using your git client and SSH, you are authenticating using the git user. I do not know the permissions for the git user, and you are advised on not changing the permissions.

Comment: nothing you have said so far is related to the question, thanks for sharing anyway.